# How to get an instance of sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem on a Windows machine?

Tags: java, java.nio.file

In particular, I'd like to use the (unfortunately not visible) **`sun.nio.fs.Globs.toUnixRegexPattern(String glob)`**.

#### Ok, stepping back and giving a bit of context

I have an iterator of pathes into a remote, unix-like file system (think `ssh unixhost find path -type f`). I also have a user-supplied glob pattern which I now want to match each path against.

On a unix machine, the following works just fine:

```
matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + glob);
// ...
for (String s : remoteFind(...)) {
    if (matcher.matches(Paths.get(s))) {
       // matches, do something
    }
}
```

But when this is run on Windows, the same program totally fails because the FileSystems.getDefault() returns a Windows filesystem (the horror, the horror) and '\' is used as separator, etc. You get the picture. Nothing matches.

Of course I can stop all this nonsense and just rewrite (or rather, copy) `sun.nio.fs.Globs.toUnixRegexPattern(String glob)`, but is there another, more elegant way?

Comment: `PathMatcher` supports `glob` and `regex`, maybe you'll have more luck with regex. Or perhaps include the pattern into `remoteFind` as it is executed on a real unix machine?

Comment: Thanks, but a glob it has to be. The part about remoteFind being a 'find' executed on a remote unix machine was just an illustration. In reality, the iterator is local and lists "files" on S3 (objects named according to the UNIX convention).  For now I just copied the glob to regexp conversion from sun.nio.fs.Globs and all is well. It's unsatisfying, though.

Comment: if it meets your license requirements, then leave it so, I suppose. Otherwise, if this method exists in default jre for windows, try calling it with reflection. But yes, both ways are not really good. Maybe you can convert your glob to match windows separator style in runtime? Show your file structure and some sample glob.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy: the file structure is really similar to anything you would get with 'find $root -type f' on any unix/linux like filesystem.  The glob can be anything that would work with the -name option of find, so for example '???*.csv', although I would prefer it to also allow '{...}' constructs such as '???*.csv{,.gz}', as implemented by most shells and also by perl's File::Glob (and, as it turns out, by `sun.nio.fs.Globs.toUnixRegexPattern(String glob)` as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so just to close this question, as stated in the comments I ended up writing a method in my `FileUtil` that is almost verbatim a copy of `sun.nio.fs.Globs.toUnixRegexPattern(String glob)`.  Works great.

If somebody finds a better way please add a different answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not make any file system operations locally, you could try to set

```
 -Dfile.separator=/
```

system variable to mimic the unix path separator. This variable should be passed to JVM on startup

Comment: Setting predefined system properties is almost always a bad idea. In the best case it will be ignored, but you can also break the JVM this way (learned that the hard way by accidentally setting java.home).

Answer (score 0):

As `sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem` is not even part of my Windows JDK, I went one step back and looked for `FileSystemProvider`s that are available on all platforms. So I found `JrtFileSystemProvider`, which can be (mis-)used to get a Unix-like path matcher on Windows (the following is copy & paste from some Kotlin code, but you get the idea):

```kotlin
val jrtFileSystem = FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI("jrt:/"))
// ...
val pattern = "..."
val matcher = jrtFileSystem.getPathMatcher("glob:$pattern")
// ...
matcher.matches(jrtFileSystem.getPath("path/to/match"))
```